# Replacement rule does not output a list

Tags: replacement

Why is this giving me a list as an output:

```
x/.x->{1,2,3}
```

> {1,2,3}

But this isn't

```
0/.x->{1,2,3}
```

> 0

**I would like to achieve** and would also *expect*:

```
0/.x->{1,2,3}
```

> {0,0,0}

There must be an inbuilt function that does this:

```
myReplacementrule[expr_, from_, to_] :=Table[expr /. {from -> to[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length[to]}];

myReplacementrule[k, k, {1, 2, 3, 4}]
myReplacementrule[0, k, {1, 2, 3, 4}]
```

> {1,2,3,4}
>
> {0,0,0,0}

Which one is it? "/. ->" doesnt do it.

Comment: type `/.`, hit F1, check examples and definition, let us know what is not working as planned. It is not clear what do you think `/.` or `->` really do.

Comment: `x/.x->{1,2,3}` means: _in expression `x`, replace each `x` with `{1,2,3}`_. `0/.x->{1,2,3}` means: _in expression `0`, replace each `x` with `{1,2,3}`_, but there is no `x` in `0`, so there is nothing to be replaced; or, if you replace  in `0` each `x` with `{1,2,3}`, you'll get `0`.

Comment: Looking at the -2 status right now I am curious why this is considered a bad question?

Comment: What is the point of `k` in `myReplacementrule[0, k, {1, 2, 3, 4}]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To turn `0` into `{0, 0, 0}` you need a list of 3 lists of rules (`->`)

```
x /. {{x -> 1}, {x -> 2}, {x -> 3}}
0 /. {{x -> 1}, {x -> 2}, {x -> 3}}
```

> {1, 2, 3}
>   {0, 0, 0}

Comment: How can I apply this more easily:
`0 /. {Thread[x -> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]}` is not quite doing the trick

Comment: @MrPuh `0 /. ({x -> #} & /@ {1, 2, 3, 4, 5})`

Answer (score 1):

```
myReplacementrule // Attributes = HoldAll;

myReplacementrule[expr_, var_Symbol, stuff_List
] := Table[expr, {var, stuff}]

myReplacementrule[k, k, {1, 2, 3, 4}]
myReplacementrule[0, k, {1, 2, 3, 4}]
```